# The most efficient way to insert variable into the array of pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What is the most efficient way to insert variable into the array of pointers(insert into the second dimension) in C? Like this:

```
    char * get_time(void)
    {
         time_t rawtime;
         struct tm * ptm;
         time (&rawtime);
         ptm = gmtime ( &rawtime );
         ptm->tm_hour = ptm->tm_hour - 4;
         return asctime(ptm);
    }

    char *some_array[] = {
        "some" get_time() "string",
        "some string"
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for `snprintf()` but you can't do it in the array initializer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot concatenate strings that way in C.  You're going to have to set aside some memory for the final string, write to it, and assign the location of that memory to the array element.  This is about as good as it's going to get:

```
/**
 * Set aside your array of pointers.  You can still initialize
 * array elements with string literals or NULL if you wish, like so
 */
char *some_array[] = {NULL, "some string", "another string", NULL ...}; 

/**
 * Alternately, you could use designated initializers
 *
 * char *some_array[] = {[1]="some string", [2]="another string", ... }
 *
 * to initialize some elements, and the other elements will be 
 * initialized to NULL. 
 */
...
char *timestr = get_time();   // get your time string

size_t bufLen = strlen( "some " ) + strlen( timestr ) + strlen( " string" ) + 1;
some_array[0] = malloc( bufLen * sizeof *some_array[0] ); // allocate memory for
                                                          // your formatted string 

if ( some_array[0] )
{
  sprintf( some_array[0], "some %s string", timestr );   // and write to it.
}
```

**Edit**

Note that at some point you will want to deallocate that memory using the `free` function:

```
free( some_array[0] );
```

Unfortunately, you'll have to keep track of which elements you allocated memory for vs. the elements you just assigned a string literal to.  Attempting to `free` a string literal will most likely lead to a runtime error.